# Store all the items from a HTML table in to a Scripting Dictionary, adding also the duplicates values

Tags: html, vba, excel, scripting.dictionary

I want to store in a dictionary all the items found in a html table.

I have problems when I have duplicates, because my below code don't store again the item, and I need all the items from this table, even if there is any duplicate.

If I have duplicate values like **Round 38**, where another *Match3* has the same round number, I want to list again those duplicate values.

The results should look like this:

**Round 38**

Match1

Match2

**Round 37**

Match1

Match2

**Round 38**

Match3

Match4

..............

```
Sub Get_URL_Addresses_test()

Dim URL As String
Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
Dim dictObj As Object: Set dictObj = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim tRowID As String

URL = "http://www.flashscore.ro/fotbal/anglia/premier-league-2015-2016/rezultate/"

With ie
    .navigate URL
    .Visible = True
    Do Until .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
    Set HTMLdoc = .document
End With


For Each objLink In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")

   If Left(objLink.innerText, 4) = "Show" Or Left(objLink.innerText, 4) = "Arat" Then

        objLink.Click
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        objLink.Click
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        objLink.Click
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        'Exit For

   End If

Next objLink


With HTMLdoc

    Set tblSet = .getElementById("fs-results")
    Set mTbl = tblSet.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0)
    Set tRows = mTbl.getElementsByTagName("tr")
    With dictObj

        For Each tRow In tRows

            If tRow.getAttribute("Class") = "event_round" Then
                tRowClass = tRow.innerText
                'MsgBox tRowClass
                If Not .Exists(tRowClass) Then
                    .add tRowClass, Empty
                End If
            End If

            tRowID = Mid(tRow.ID, 5)
            If Not .Exists(tRowID) Then
                .add tRowID, Empty
            End If


        Next tRow
    End With
End With

i = 14
For Each Key In dictObj

    If Left(Key, 5) = "Runda" Or Left(Key, 5) = "Round" Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2) = Key
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2) = "http://www.flashscore.ro/meci/" & Key & "/#sumar-meci"
    End If

    i = i + 1

    'MsgBox Key
    'Debug.Print Key
Next Key

Set ie = Nothing
MsgBox "Process Completed"

End Sub
```

Comment: It's .exists, remove that.  You need to add an incrementing key and add the trowclass as the item.  Why do you want to add duplicates?  You could run an incremental count in a parallel dictionary.  Otherwise use a straight forward array..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store your items in a generic container that allows duplicates, such as collection or array. But since you are storing them in a dictionary, as `keys`, it probably means that you want later a fast search for existence of some items. A possible solution would be to "count" the number of appearances of each item (key) and store this number in the corresponding value field.

```
If tRow.getAttribute("Class") = "event_round" Then
    tRowClass = tRow.innerText
    dim n as Integer: n = dictObj.Item(tRowClass) ' creates and returns 0 if no exist yet
    dictObj.Item(tRowClass) = n + 1
End If
```

Later you will be able check for the existence of any key in the dictionary and also you have the number of appearances of that key.

**EDIT**

As I suspected, you're using the dictionary just as a normal container, but since you want to allow for duplicates, Dictiobary is not the way you go. Just use a `Collection`. Here's the minimal change to your code:

`Set dictObj = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")` --> `Set dictObj = new Collection`

> `If Not .Exists(tRowClass) Then .add tRowClass, Empty End If`

Replace the above stuff (3 line) with:

```
.add tRowClass
```

That's it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! After the storage I want to write all the items of the Dictionary (including duplicates) in the Excel cells (starting with "B2"), but keeping the same order how it was stored in the Dictionary.

Comment: @Flo-Rin ok, I see. That's feasible. But I would I have a question, why to use a dictionary in the first place, instead of a normal container, such as an array, since you want to allow for duplicates, while a dictionary is usually used to manage or eliminate dup0licates?

Comment: I don't know very well VBA programming, so this code is what I found on some web pages.

Comment: The solution depends much on what you do later with this container. Edit your question to add that part of code.

Comment: @Flo-Rin plz see the EDIT for the minimal changes to do to your code. Basically we will use a `Collection` instead of the dictionary.

Comment: @ A.S.H: Thank you very much for your help! It works very well.

Comment: @Flo-Rin good to know it works. But it seems like you never check the acceptance mark for your questions. Please take the habit to do it so people around will be happier to help you.

Comment: @ A.S.H: Sorry, I am quite new on this website, and I don't know all the rules. You speak about the "green V", right?

Comment: @Flo-Rin yes I was talking about that. Never mind, thanks for answering :)